# searching by exact value in existing varchar column vs add new boolean column

Tags: postgresql

Which solution is better for performance in postgres database:

- search by exact value of existing varchar column
- create new boolean column in existing database and search by its value

table contains user id, date of planned job(reservation), date when started job, date when finished job, job name
for now it has around 10k records and it expand by around 2k/year

we want to allow job without earlier reservation but still keep log of start/end date so when backend detect this type of job and it create record with specific name

there is 2 way to see this records: by user which see only planned records and admins who see all

We can do it by excluding for user this specific name or create boolean column with value true if job was created by backend and false otherwise

Comment: It depends. What's the size of that varchar column, what's the size of the table, what's the use case, etc. This question is far too broad.

Comment: added more info